# R: Merge multiple dataframes which are now elements of a list

Tags: r

I ran a double for loop and stored some data into a list. 
Specifically, I stored each data frame of 15 columns and approximately
60 to 70 rows as one element of the list weather. 
For example

```
 > weather[[4]][[5]]
   TimeCEST TemperatureC Dew.PointC Humidity Sea.Level.PressurehPa VisibilityKm
1  12:00 AM           12          8       71                  1013           20
2  12:20 AM           11          7       76                  1013           10
3  12:50 AM           11          7       76                  1013           10
4   1:00 AM           11          8       71                  1013           30
```

Now, I want to merge by row all these data frames (about 360) into one data frame.

I tried running a for loop again and rbind but it gives:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
names do not match previous names.
```

Then I tried this:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) {
  dd<-merge(x,y,by=0); rownames(dd)<-dd$Row.names; dd[-1]
}, weather)
```

but it gives:

```
 Error in data.frame(list(TimeCET = c(19L, 21L, 23L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 25L, 27L,  : 
    arguments imply differing number of rows: 71, 72, 67, 68
```

As a follow up I tried to replace NUll values with NA, in case that was causing the problem, but it is the same.

Could you please explain the problem to me and indicate a way to solve it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `weather` is a nested list of data.frames. Maybe you combine the data in two steps, like in this untested code

```
second_lvl <- function(lst) {
    # make one df from weather[[i]][[1]], weather[[i]][[2]], etc.
    do.call(rbind, lst)
}

# this should make res a list of data.frames
res <- lapply(weather, FUN=second_lvl)

# this should combine the data.frames
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
```